# Why can I not shorten this path?

Tags: tikz-arrows

Trying to shorten the path at the end of this MWE I am getting the errors:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,positioning,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=1.8cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[block](column1) {Column 1};
    \node[block, right of=column1, node distance=2.05cm](column2) {Column 2};
    \node[block, right of=column2, node distance=2.05cm](column3) {Column 3};
    \node[block, right of=column3, node distance=2.05cm](columnn) {Column N};
    \node[block, below of=column1, node distance=1cm](value1s) {Value 1};
    \node[block, below of=column2, node distance=1cm](value2s) {Value 2};
    \node[block, below of=column3, node distance=1cm](value3s) {...};
    \node[block, below of=columnn, node distance=1cm](valuens) {Value N};

    \node[block, right of=columnn, node distance=4cm, yshift=1.5104cm](column) {Column};
    \node[block, below of=column, node distance=1cm](value1) {Value 1};
    \node[block, below of=value1, node distance=1cm](value2) {Value 2};
    \node[block, below of=value2, node distance=1cm](value3) {...};
    \node[block, below of=value3, node distance=1cm](valuen) {Value N};

  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=2mm}] (value1.north east) -- (valuen.south east) node [black,midway,xshift=1.7cm,text width=1.8cm] (aggappl) {Lorem ipsum dolor};

  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=2mm,mirror}] (value1s.south west) -- (valuens.south east) node [black,midway,yshift=-1cm] (aggnoappl) {Lorem ipsum dolor};

    \path [line,shorten>=2mm,shorten<=2mm] (valuens.north east) -> (value2.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Error messages:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/shorten>',
to which you passed '2mm', and I am going to ignore it.
Perhaps you misspelled it. \path [line,shorten>=2mm,shorten<=2mm] (
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/shorten<',
to which you passed '2mm', and I am going to ignore it.
Perhaps you misspelled it. \path [line,shorten>=2mm,shorten<=2mm] (
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a typo. You need a space between `shorten` and `<` or `>`.

Comment: I would have never...